# jquery : how to apply same changes inside mulitple container with same class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

i am trying to move a .details outside of .buttons

```
   <div class="product-actions">product 1
      <div class="buttons buttons_3 group">buttons
         <a class="details" title="Détails" rel="nofollow" >link</a>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="product-actions">product 2
      <div class="buttons buttons_3 group">buttons
        <a class="details" title="Détails" rel="nofollow" >link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

this do the trick

```
if ($('.product-actions').length )
    {       

    $('.product-actions').prepend("<div id='new_details_location'></div>");
    $(".details").prependTo("#new_details_location");

    $('.buttons_3').attr('class','buttons buttons_2 group');        
    }
```

the problem is there is more than one product and all a.details get moved to the first product div instead of being prepend at the beginning of each div .product-actions:

http://jsfiddle.net/upKhq/2/
any idea?

Comment: Please fix your jsFiddle. There are bits missing.

Comment: The clue was in your own question `each div .product-actions` :)

Comment: also you can use jquery addClass('buttons buttons_2 group') instand of
 $('.buttons_3').attr('class','buttons buttons_2 group');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use each jquery method:

```
$('.product-actions').each(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    var new_location = $("<div id='new_details_location'></div>").prependTo(self);
    self.find(".details").prependTo(new_location);
    self.find('.buttons_3').attr('class','buttons buttons_2 group');   
});
```

And you should not use the same id for two elements.

Answer (score 2):

Try this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9AN4w/)

```
$('.product-actions').each(function () {
    $new = $(this).prepend("<div class='new_details_location'></div>");
    $(".details", $(this)).prependTo($new);

    $('.buttons_3', $(this)).attr('class', 'buttons buttons_2 group');
});
```

You made a few mistakes:
your selectors were not context sensitive and you were using `id` in `prependTo` which has to be unique, but you had 2 divs with the same id.

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean to do this instead?

```
$('.product-actions').each(function() {
    $elem = $("<div class='new_details_location'></div>");
    $(this).find(".details").prependTo($elem);
    $(this).prepend($elem);
});

$('.buttons_3').attr('class', 'buttons buttons_2 group');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/upKhq/4/

Answer (score 0):

use `.each`, and use $(this) to refer to the current `.product-actions` element. Also you cant have multiple ids that are the same, only the first one would ever be used

```
if ($('.product-actions').length ) {       
   $('.product-actions').each(function() {
      var newDetailLocation = $('<div></div>');
      $(this).prepend(newDetailLocation);
      $(".details",$(this)).prependTo(newDetailLocation);
      $('.buttons_3',$(this)).attr('class','buttons buttons_2 group');        
   });
}
```